# Android Camera Flash opening Delay

Tags: android, camera

I am using camera flash to blink, but when I press button for camera flash to blink but the flash is blinking after some milliseconds, i want that flash should be blink immediately after pressing button? How to reduce that time delay.

Here is my code to start flash on button click:

```
                cam = Camera.open();
                params = cam.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                cam.setParameters(params);
                cam.startPreview();
```

Comment: Hard to suggest improvements if we don't know what you have done.

Comment: The following permissions must be set in your AndroidManifest.xml:

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" />